# cannot compile rinside with armadillo examples

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo, rinside

I am trying to compile the Rarmadillo example with Rinside  and I keep getting:

```
In file included from rinside_arma0.cpp:8:0:
/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:26:6: error: #error "The file 'Rcpp.h' should not be included. Please correct to include only 'RcppArmadillo.h'."
```

I googled it but I keep getting the source code per se. Any ideas ?

The code is :

```
// -*- c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-
//
// Simple example using Armadillo classes
//
// Copyright (C) 2012  Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois

#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);      // create an embedded R instance

    std::string cmd = "diag(3)";    // create a Matrix in r 

    arma::mat m = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(R.parseEval(cmd)); // parse, eval + return result

    std::cout << m << std::endl;    // and use Armadillo i/o  

    exit(0);
}
```

and compiled it using:

```
g++ -I/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/include -I/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include -I"/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -I/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/RInside/include -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include   rinside_arma0.cpp  -L/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/lib -lR  -lf77blas -latlas -llapack -L/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/Rcpp/lib -L/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/RInside/lib  -o rinside_arma0
```

Comment: Can you put the code in rinside_arma0.cpp and the command you used to compile it

Comment: You should consider using a Makefile to simplify your compilation process and make it more easier to understand. Look for example at `/usr/local64/opt/R-2.15.2/lib/R/library/RInside/examples/armadillo/Makefile`. Which platform do you use ?

Comment: I do use the Makefile. I just copy-pasted the compile command used by the makefile as you requested. Linux PC

Comment: I tried and  I have also a problem...as soon as I find a solution, I'll post it. Meanwhile I hope that @eddelbuettel will read this question and propose you a proper solution. Sorry

Comment: Have you tried including RcppArmadillo.h before Rinside.h ?

Comment: OMG that worked ! Put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error you get is because `Rcpp.h` is included before `RcppArmadillo.h`, `Rcpp.h` is included by `RInside.h`.

For the magic that `RcppArmadillo` gives you, the file `RcppArmadillo.h` needs to be loaded before `Rcpp.h`. So I suggest you do this:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RInside.h>
```

Comment: The same is true for the second example in that directory as well, and the reordering fix was committed in April -- we just have not released RInside since.